# keep getting the same image on jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon, tablecellrenderer

*imgPath* variable keep printing different *links* in the console. But it only gives the last image(image of the last assigned link) in every row.

```
private void fillTable(){
try {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    ArrayList<Cab> allCabs = ServerConnector.getInstance().getCabController().getAllCabs();
    for (Cab cab : allCabs) {
        Object[] row = {cab.getId(), "", cab.getLicenceNo()}; 
        dtm.addRow(row);
        imgPath = cab.getImgLink();
        Sysytem.out.println(imgPath);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (NotBoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object value, boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        if (value!=null) {
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgPath));
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But it only gives the last image(image of the last assigned link) in every row.

There is only every a single renderer for a column. When the cell is rendered the renderer references the "imgPath" variable (which can only ever contain one reference at a time) which is of course the last value you assigned to it.

If you want to render an image in a table, then you should store the ImageIcon in the TableModel. So you should add the Icon to the TableModel like:

```
String imgPath = cab.getImgLink();
Object[] row = {cab.getId(), new ImageIcon(imgPath), cab.getLicenceNo()}; 
dtm.addRow(row);
```

Then when you create the DefaultTableModel you need to override the `getColumnClass()` method of the TableModel and the JTable will use a default renderer to display the Icon, so you don't need to write a custom renderer.

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableIcon extends JPanel
{
    public TableIcon()
    {
        Icon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("about16.gif");
        Icon addIcon = new ImageIcon("add16.gif");
        Icon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

        String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {aboutIcon, "About"},
            {addIcon, "Add"},
            {copyIcon, "Copy"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Icon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableIcon());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```